# Tabbed navigation, text prob

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-fragments

I just started learning app building, and I need a little help.
I read a tutorial about making Tabbed Navigation and I can't get something to work.
As I followed the tutorial I made two tabs, each send you to a different fragment ( each fragment just holds text ), my problem is that I am unable to show the text in each fragment.
I searched throughout the forum but I couldn't find something similar

This is my screen with the tabs :

```
    package com.example.tabspractice2;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.app.ActionBar;

    public class tabsScreen extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener1 = new tabs(this, "com.example.tabspractice2.tab1");
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
                tab1.setText("tab1");
                tab1.setTabListener(tabListener1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab1);

    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener2 = new tabs(this, "com.example.tabspractice2.tab2");
    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
                tab2.setText("tab2");
                tab2.setTabListener(tabListener2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

This is the TabListener:

```
    package com.example.tabspractice2;

    import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.content.Context;


    public class tabs implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    Context _context;
    String _tabFragmentClassName;
    Fragment _tabFragment = null;
    String content;

    public tabs (Context context, String tabFragmentClassName){
        _context = context;
        _tabFragmentClassName = tabFragmentClassName;
    }



    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
      if (_tabFragment == null){
        _tabFragment = Fragment.instantiate(_context, _tabFragmentClassName);
        arg1.add(_tabFragment, content);
      }
      else 
        arg1.attach(_tabFragment);

    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
      arg1.detach(_tabFragment);

    }
@Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }
```

This is one of my tabs ( they both look the same )

```
    package com.example.tabspractice2;

    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class tab1 extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedIns){
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
}
    }
```

each of them directs to an xml file which looks like this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/tab1TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="tab1" />

    </ScrollView>
```

which should load up the text, but for some reason it won't show, I think it has something to do with the "content" in the tabs class, but it's beyond my understanding ...
in the tutorial they directed the content to R.id, but it gives me an error and I am unable to change the R file correctly ... so I created a new field, I guess that what's wrong ...